# to submit request in python mechanize for javascript

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

I am working with the page
http://index.cepd.gov.tw/inQuery.aspx?lang=2&type=it02

in this page, I am submitting values using python mechanize.
but, when I submit it, it gives me the same url.
I want the url of the next page after submit.

Is it due to javascript?
Is any way to work with javascript to get next url?

Answer (score 1):

If after submission you are getting the same page, I assume the javascript is setting some hidden field after validation.

Try stopping javascript execution in your browser and submitting the form (from the browser).
If it doesn't work, then mechanize won't be enough (since it doesn't support javascript execution) and you will need some browser automation tool.